# Serialize Object like a form in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, serialization, post

I am looking to transmit a post request through HTTP, the body needs to contain information from a ValueObject I've already created. Essentially I need to serialize the object (which has multiple dimensions). The problem I'm running into is that I don't want to transmit the data as JSON or XML but as a multidimensional array. It works in HTML forms like:

data:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [a] => Array
                (
                    [1] =>  abcd
                )

            [b] => defg
        )

    [d] => ghij
)
```

request body (decoded):

```
a[a][1]=abcd&a[b]=defg&d=ghij
```

Is there any library out there that does this kind of serialization already? I'm using as3httpclientlib, so I don't have the convenience of the mx.rpc family. I've spent the past several hours trying to roll my own solution, but I'm pretty sure I'd be better off with a solution someone has put more time and thought into.

Comment: All the answers below simply show you a way to serialize an object into String. This is what JSON is - serialized object into String. JSON CAN serialize multidimensional array or whatever you need. There is no need  to make your own (de)serializer.
And since you cannot use AMF, which I admire most, I don't understand why you don't like JSON :)

Comment: This is a 4 year old question first off. And it's certainly not that I "don't like JSON," rather, I needed to encode the object in a URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try AMF to solve your problem (you have different library according to your programming language).
The main advantage is that you can do mapping object to object (using Value Object) and preserve the data type (like arrays).

I'm using the plugin amf with Symfony and here is an example of data returned :

SabreAMF_TypedObject Object
(
    [amfClassName:private] => Product

```
[amfData:private] => Array
    (
        [code] => 1970A007
        [designation] => 1970 PELL A007 BLANC
        [description] => Vernis extra souple extra brillant
        [sommeil] => 
        [name] => 1970
        [base] => A Stretch Enduit
        [composition] => 43% PL 57% PU
        [laize] => 137-140 cm
        [weight] => 588 g/ml
        [dechirure] => 10 daN/9 daN
        [abrasion] => 5000
        [xenotest] => 4/5
        [non_feu] => Non
        [Color] => SabreAMF_TypedObject Object
            (
                [amfClassName:private] => Color
                [amfData:private] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 124
                        [name] => BLANC
                    )

            )
```

Some explanation :

```
[amfClassName:private] => Product
```

My Object is typed. As3 side i have a Product Value Object too wich contains array properties like "code", "designation", "description",... and Color (another typed Array with Value Object Color)

So you can easily have a multidimensional structure arrays...

Comment: My issue with AMF is simply that I'm using a REST API that needs to be open to others outside of the AMF world. I am trying to prevent this sucker from getting complicated. And IMO adding another content-type is going a little to far.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

so here is something more simple using URLVariables :

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.URLVariables;

public class URLVariableExample extends Sprite {

    private static const URL_SERVER:String = "http://localhost/testURL.php";
    private var loader:URLLoader;

    public function URLVariableExample() {
        init();
    }

    private function init() : void {
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(URL_SERVER);

        var urlVar:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    var a : Array = ["toto", "titi", "loulou"];
        urlVar["urlTest[a][a]"] = a.toString();
        urlVar["urlTest[a][b]"] = "desc";
        urlVar["urlTest[d]"] = "defg";

        request.data = urlVar;
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

        loader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);       
        loader.load(request);
    }

    private function loaderComplete(event : Event) : void {
        loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
        trace(URLLoader(event.currentTarget).data);
    }
}
```

}

I requested a php file and just put a simple var_dump function.
Trace return :

```
array(2) {["d"]=>string(4) "defg"["a"]=> array(2) {["a"]=>string(16) "toto,titi,loulou["b"]=>string(4) "desc"}}
```

Comment: But it doesn't serialize an object. I'd have to parse the object by hand.... which is more the problem than formatting the request.

Comment: @Noah soon or later you'll have to format your request in some way... no ?

Comment: Yes, and I suppose what I meant was: If I can get the properties of an object (full recursion) then I could easily format the output. My biggest problem is getting the full recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url:String = 'http://localhost/dump.php';
var params:Object = {
    test: 'ok',
    nested_1: {
        nested_2: {
            nested_3: {
                nested_4: {
                    hello: 'mf',
                    str: '~!@#$%^&*()_+'
                }
            }
        }
    },
};

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

parameters = fixParameters(parameters || {});

for (var key:String in parameters) {
    variables[key] = parameters[key];
}

request.data = variables;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(request);
```

and here is fixParameters method

```
private function fixParameters(data:Object, parameters:Object = null, prefixes:Array = null):Object {
    var setPrefix:Array;
    var prefixKey:String;

    if (!parameters) {
        parameters = {};
    }

    if (!prefixes) {
        prefixes = [];
    }

    for (var key:String in data) {
        setPrefix = prefixes.concat([key]);

        if (typeof(data[key]) == 'object') {
            parameters = fixParameters(data[key], parameters, setPrefix);
        } else {
            prefixKey = '';
            for (var i:Number = 0; i < setPrefix.length; i++) {
                prefixKey += i == 0 ? setPrefix[i] :  '[' + setPrefix[i] + ']';
            }
            parameters[prefixKey] = data[key];
        }
    }

    return parameters;
}
```